# Capistrano 3 discards :user variable when executing remote SSH command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

Trying to test Capistrano from scratch.

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
```

deploy.rb:

```
role :testrole, 'x.x.x.x'
set :user, 'ubuntu'
```

The test.rb task:

```
namespace :test do
desc "Uptime on servers"
task :uptime do
  on roles(:testrole) do
    execute "uptime" 
  end
end
 end
```

cap command:

```
cap production test:uptime
```

output:

```
INFO [c077da7f] Running /usr/bin/env uptime on x.x.x.x
DEBUG [c077da7f] Command: /usr/bin/env uptime
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
```

Dont have a problem to login from the shell using the same user and key.
While logged in the remote server, I can see in auth.log that an empty user given while executing the cap:

```
test-srv sshd[1459]: Invalid user  from x.x.x.x
```

What do I miss ?
Thanks!

Comment: P.S. `env.fetch(:user)` inside the task shows the correct user

Comment: any chance of accepting my answer?

Answer (score 12):

If you take a look at their example code, supplied when you `cap install` your project, you'll see something like this in `staging.rb` and `production.rb`:

```ruby
# Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary
# server in each group is considered to be the first
# unless any hosts have the primary property set.
# Don't declare `role :all`, it's a meta role
role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}

# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server
# definition into the server list. The second argument
# something that quacks like a hash can be used to set
# extended properties on the server.
server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
```

You'll either want to specify your user in one of those places, or use `fetch(:user)` to grab it programmatically at runtime. E.g.,

```ruby
server 'example.com', user: fetch(:user), roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
```

Comment: Well, I’m glad some folks have found this helpful recently! Perhaps @Bigmyx can make it the accepted answer?